# Help for roof ideas for very large cat enclosure

Tags: roofing

I am building a very large enclosure for our cats. Approximate will be 20’ x 30’ 30’ x 30’ (*pie shaped lot so one of the four sides is shorter*.)

One side will use the house (*stucco*) as a wall. Two sides will use existing 6’ cedar fence as walls. The fourth side will need to be built and I’ll use steel fencing wire so they can see out.

I’m in Canada so we get a lot of snow sometimes.

How do we build a roof for this? (*I’m leaning towards fencing wire so they get sunlight through*).

Comment: Do you need something to simply keep the cats in, or are you trying to also provide shade in the summer and protection from the snow in the winter?

Comment: What's the compass direction of the side they will get to "look out"?

Comment: Not sure why the down vote , reversed.  If you give a down vote you should cite the reason, this looks fine to me a diy enclosure and the op is asking for advice.

Comment: Are you a lion tamer? How strong does this structure need to be ?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's been abandoned.

Answer (score 1):

Under conditions of low wind even a wire "roof" can pick up a lot of snow load.

So, a large roof area like that will require a lot of support, even if it's wire fencing. That can be provided by rows of posts with heavy wire to support the fencing between posts, and you could exploit the posts as support for cat entertainment, perches, etc.

Whether your cats will want to be out there once the snow makes it through to the ground may vary with your cats (or even with the age of the cat, most of mine got disgusted with snow after the first year or two.) Our very furry robust barn cats basically burrowed into the nests they made (we helped by stacking bales to make a starting cavity for them) in the hayloft and patrolled inside the barn over winters, rather than roaming out through the snow. Our indoor cats rarely spend much time at all outdoors in winter, and prefer areas without snow when they do go out.

A solid roof may have a lot more impact on your property taxes than a wire "roof." One possible intermediate approach would be greenhouse film (sheet plastic, but sturdy and UV resistant for years) which is not normally classed the same as a "permanent structure" for tax purposes. You'd need to support it in a manner that would shed snow, and that might be difficult, expensive, or require changing your plans if the fences you are using for walls are also boundary fences (can't just dump snow on the neighbors property.)

Answer (score 0):

A wire roof will allow birds to sit on top and poop on your cats. You think that's funny? I have seen it happen! Crows in particular have a vengeful streak in them. I would use corrugated fiberglass roofing panels, set at an angle appropriate to allow snow to slide off easily.